# Как изменить url страницы , сайт заглушка без СMS

Tags: .htaccess, url, чпу

Имеется сайт-заглушка для домена. С помощью `.htacces` настроил редирект с `http` на `https`.   Изменил страницу, по умолчанию, с `Index.html` на `myfirstpage.html`и сделал так, чтобы сайт отображался по адресу `https://mysite.com`.
Собственно сайт имеет всего из 2 страниц. Первая `myfirstpage`, основная - Русский язык.
Вторая `mysecondpage.html` - Английский язык.
Как сделать, чтобы URL второй страницы был не `https:// mysite.com/mysecondpage.html`, а просто `https://mysite.com/en`. Знаю средствами `сms` делается просто, но как быть если сайт состоит всего из 2-x файлов `html`. Только начал разбираться в `.htacces` и еще не понял как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуется данный функционал, в зависимости какой веб сервер используется, либо с помощью mod_rewrite на веб сервере с apache (httpd) и правилами маршрутизации в nginx.

1. Для apache:

   `RewriteEngine On # включает модуль
   RewriteRule    ^en/?$    mysecondpage.html    [NC,L] # создает правило`

Для работы должен быть включен модуль mod_rewrite на веб сервере.

2. Для nginx

   `location /en {
       rewrite ^/en/?$ /mysecondpage.html break;
   }`

RewriteRule и rewrite создают правило обработки url, начинающихся с "en" и перенаправляют на mysecondpage.html, с возможностью передачи параметра.

Параметр можно передать через слэш, например `en/param1`, в таком случае param1 будет доступен в mysecondpage.html